# Polymer 1.0: Two-way data binding: <iron-form> to/from Firebase

Tags: forms, firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, 2-way-object-databinding

I want to two-way databind the field values of an `iron-form` to a Firebase node (representing user-defined ***settings***, for example).

settings.html

```
<dom-module id="my-settings">
  <template>
    <firebase-document location="[[firebaseUrl]]"
                       data="{{form}}">
    </firebase-document>
    <form is="iron-form" id="form">
      <paper-checkbox id="history"
                      name="history"
                      on-change="_computeForm"
                      >Save history
      </paper-checkbox>
      <!-- ... -->
      <!-- All types of form fields go here -->
      <!-- ... -->
    </form>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-settings',
        _computeForm: function() {
          this.form = this.$.form.serialize();
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

This form needs to:

- persist its state to firebase upon changes (i.e., *first-way* binding — client to firebase) and
- set form fields to their saved values upon loading  (i.e., *second-way* binding —  firebase to client — completing the *two-way* binding).

### Questions

> 1. Please provide the best practice solution for accomplishing this.
> 2. Is it possible to bind the entire form (***declaratively***?) and avoid having to ***imperatively*** set each form field value independently upon load?
> 3. I encourage pseudocode or concepts that point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iron-form` is not necessary. You need to bind a `<firebase-document>` to an element property (representing the form) and bind the form field values to that property's sub-properties.

[Also, see this **todo-list** example](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/todo-list/blob/master/app/elements/todo-item/todo-item.html).

settings.html

```
<dom-module id="my-settings">
  <template>
    <firebase-document location="[[firebaseUrl]]" data="{{form}}"></firebase-document>
    <paper-checkbox checked="{{form.history}}">Save history</paper-checkbox>
    <paper-input value="{{form.name}}" label="Name"></paper-input>
    <!-- Other form fields go here -->
  </template>
  <script>
    (function() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-settings',
        properties: {
          form: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true
          }
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: what about validation ? let's say you want to validate the form.name

Comment: @integratingweb You can use paper-input's pattern or allowedPattern properties for validation. See the demo at elements.polymer-project.org.